# Custom deferred deep link service

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, branch.io

I am wondering how can I create my own Firebase Dynamic Link service, does anyone know of some good resource on the topic? What I am most curious about is how does the deep link persistence works, in case where user does not have app installed, he is navigated to download it, he downloads it and on first launch - deep link which led him to the download is still present. How can I achieve this?

At the moment I am using Firebase Dynamic links but since service is set to be canceled I want to create my own, I have custom backend and a website just cannot figure out the persistence thing.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android and Google Play, you might want to check out the [Play Install Referrer](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library).

Answer (score -1):

You can use Branch for deferred deeplinking services. Branch is a great alternative to Firebase Dynamic Links as Branch’s deep links make it even easier to handle the complexity of app linking across platforms like iOS and Android, channels, and use cases.

For more information or queries refer [branch help portal](https://help.branch.io/)